# Shimano Nexus Inter8 hard to twist grip shift in higher gears

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, nexus, grip-shifter

After my local bike shop did a tune-up on my HaiBike Radius, it has become very hard to twist my grip shift into higher gears when I am riding.  The grips shift twists easily when I shift down or when the bike is stationary.  When I ride, it is so hard to twist that my wrist is sore by the time I get to work. My bike has a Shimano Nexus Inter8 SG-C6001 internally geared hub.  I took it back to the bike shop but they said that this is normal because the grip shift is connected to a cable that pulls on a spring.  As you shift into higher gears, the spring gets extended and it is harder to twist. I just don't think this is normal since it is noticeably different than before the tune-up.  The bike shop said they replaced the gear cable from the grip shift to the hub during the tune-up.  The yellow markers are aligned.

I am going to show the bike shop the response that [user26705 provided Kurdunas](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/shimano-nexus-7-speed-igh-high-gears-tight-shift) and the response that [Swifty provided Grigory Rechistov](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/59109/shimano-revoshift-twist-grip-unusably-tight) but my question is:

Is there anything else that the bike shop could try to reduce some of the force needed to shift into higher gears?

Unfortunately, I do not have the tools etc to complete my own repairs.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't like that before, but it is now following a cable change, there's not a lot that can explain that other than a problem with the setup of the new cable and/or housing. Common examples could be:

- Bad routing choices.
- Housing too long or too short.
- A kink in the cable or housing.
- Bad housing end prep.
- Liners or nosed ferrules left out that are needed to reduce friction.
- Mid-drive motor pinching down on the housing once mounting hardware is secured.